# Unable to connect to redshift from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am trying to read data from redshift to spark 1.5 using scala 2.10

I have built the spark-redshift package and added the amazon JDBC connector to the project, but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
```

I have authenticated in the following way:

```
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "ACCESSKEY")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","SECRETACCESSKEY")

val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
.option("url","jdbc:redshift://AWS_SERVER:5439/warehouseuser=USER&password=PWD")
.option("dbtable", "fact_time")
.option("tempdir", "s3n://bucket/path")
.load()

df.show()
```

Comment: You forgot to ship your AWS dependency jar in your spark app

Comment: thanks, I have added the following dependencies: aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.22, aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.22, aws-java-sdk-sts-1.10.22. now i am getting this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials` I repeat what I said in the comment :
You have forgot to ship your AWS dependency jar in your spark app jar

And about the second error, I'm not sure of the package but it's more likely to be the [org.apache.httpcomponents](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3) library you need. (I don't know for what you are using it thought!)

You can add the following to your maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and you'll need to assembly the whole.

**PS:** You'll always need to provide the libraries when they are not installed. You must also becareful with the size of the jar you are submitting because it can harm performance.

Comment: thanks, I indeed added the httpclient-4.5.1 and httpcore-4.4.3. now I receive this error: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils. I did read that spark-redshift library is a dependency nightmare

Comment: Yep. Indeed! But I'm not a redshift expert. As long as it stays in the spark scope, I can help. Otherwise, you'll need to ask new questions for that, sorry!